# Waiting for xseconds for AJAX response, proceed otherwise

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery Ajax snippet, for a call to a CHAT functionality, but I want to wait for only , say 2 seconds, after which I will be displaying the output which is assign for response.available is not equal to 1, for Ajax response, how a settimeout function can be used to achieve this? Below is my code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: AWC_CHAT_User.AjaxUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                  $("#chatSpinnerSection").hide();
                    if (response.available == '1') {
                        $("#chatAgentSection").show();
                        displayChatFlyOver(false);

                    } else {
                        $("#chatGeneralSection").show();
                        displayChatFlyOver(true);
                    }
                },
           error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#chatGeneralSection").show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you can use `timeout` property:

```
$.ajax({
    timeout: 2000 // 2 seconds  
    /* Other settings */
});
```

If your request is not completed after 2 seconds, then it will proceed to the `error` handler with the second argument equal to `timeout`.

```
$.ajax({
    timeout: 2000
})
.fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    if (status === 'timeout') 
    {
        // Timeout
    }
});
```